# aufs root on gentoo/funtoo

Tags: linux, gentoo, squashfs, funtoo, aufs

I have used an aufs root before on gentoo years ago, but cannot seem to get it going now.  I am using genkernel-next, I would imagine I used genkernel before as well.

I am using funtoo with aufs-sources and have aufs built-into the kernel (not a module).  I believe I need to make some initramfs changes + command-line  and /etc/fstab changes as well, but can't seem to figure out exactly what.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read [this Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Aufs), and substitute the `aufs-sources` for the hardened sources entry

Comment: Thanks, I came across the article, but it does nothing to tackle an aufs root, just being able to support aufs.

Comment: After installing the tools as per the article, I would replace or modify my root entry in `fstab`

Comment: I believe there was a parameter you needed to pass on the kernel command-line to active an init script to setup an aufs root.  I'll have to look at the initramfs to see if that is the case.

Comment: Ah, I expanded out my initramfs and see hooks for aufs.  I will post back what I find.  What I'm saying is is that the documentation is not very thorough or up-to-date for an aufs root.  Of course being that it is gentoo, there are probably 1000 different ways to do it.

Comment: I need to add the parameter aufs ... to the kernel command-line.

Comment: And, in this case, I'm using squashfs, to I need to also add looptype=squashfs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, actually, the easiest way was to simply modify the linuxrc script with exactly I wanted to do.  In that case, I added support for both aufs and overlayfs, but have opted for overlayfs since it doesn't require a special kernel patchset which would be convenient if I want to use this method / approach on other distributions.  I modified my linuxrc to support loading the squashfs image into tmpfs, using a tmpfs rw volume, and using a volume you specify for rw.  The later is really nice because you can isolate any changes you've made and either clear them out and reboot or simply reboot to a tmpfs volume to "refresh" the slate.